# How to load image from local storage using Glide

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-glide

I would like to load to imageView one image from pictures directory. With this code I alway get error, however the file exist.

This is very primitive example. It is needed for bigger project, but I want to make it as simple as possible.

build.gradle (module - only important part of code):

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1

dependencies {
 implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0"
}
```

glide 4.13.0 should be lattest version

AndroidActivity.xml(only important part):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 999) // to get permission read from external storage
  
        val image1: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()).list()?.get(0)

        Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(file)
            .into(image1)
}
```

When I debug my code I see that variable `file` exists and its name is `IMG_20220317_085955.jpg`

Error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /IMG_20220317_085955.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
```

Comment: When debugging, can you see the full file path for the file?

Comment: When I debug this part of code "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)" I see list of files with path "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20220317_085955.jpg"

Comment: Use file.exists() and file.canRead() before calling Glide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get full path I used

```
 val file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).list()
            ?.get(0)
            .toString()
```

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` will generate path `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).list()?.get(0)` get first image (if exists)

Comment: Nice, so is it working for you if you load that file path into Glide instead of the File object?

Comment: Yea I just have to add full path as String. However on some Huawei phones it doesn't works.

Comment: Good, that's what I was thinking, which is why I asked if you could get the full file path in the other comment. Nice work. Unfortunately, I don't have any answers or ideas why it wouldn't be working on Huawei phones. Does Huawei  make up a significant portion of your target audience?

Comment: I code software for company, and I don't know if they will use Huawei Phones. Current users don't use them.